# stopping a service using ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using ansible to test against a VM where I have already installed nginx.  I tried stopping the service using the command below and the resulting status displays that the process stopped.  However, on tha target server, I can see that the process is still running (and has been running for a few days).  I have the correct server in the ansible command
and am checking the right server.  Any thoughts on why the command would display the status that the service has stopped even when it does not seem to have done so.

```
ansible testserver -vvv -m service -a "name=nginx state=stopped"
Using /home/test/devops/ansible.cfg as config file
<ec2-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: test
<ec2-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=1234 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=test -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/test/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r ec2-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1467905869.39-108785461246651 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1467905869.39-108785461246651="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1467905869.39-108785461246651 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<ec2-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com> PUT /tmp/tmpqpCm5g TO /home/ali/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1467905869.39-108785461246651/service
<ec2-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=1234 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ali -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/test/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[ec2-52-87-166-241.compute-1.amazonaws.com]'
<ec2-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: test
<ec2-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=1234 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ali -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ali/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r -tt ec2-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /home/test/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1467905869.39-108785461246651/service; rm -rf "/home/test/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1467905869.39-108785461246651/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
testserver | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "arguments": "", 
            "enabled": null, 
            "name": "nginx", 
            "pattern": null, 
            "runlevel": "default", 
            "sleep": null, 
            "state": "stopped"
        }, 
        "module_name": "service"
    }, 
    "name": "nginx", 
    "state": "stopped"
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the return status of the corresponding service command? Like `systemctl` or `service` ... Ansible `service` module is more or less just a wrapper around the init commands so the easiest way to debug is to check the commands without Ansible. Another possibility would be that the process was started without a service manager.

Comment: Something similar happens while starting service. I presume, there might be an error in this module, thereby @knowhy advice is worth trying

Comment: I can run the service on the server with no issues when I use the sudo user

Answer (score 2):

in play-book:

```
- name: stop nginx service 
  service: name=nginx state=stopped
```

or

adhoc-command:to stop service

```
ansible testserver -m service -a "name=nginx state=stopped"
```

Comment: thanks for sharing - as per @MattSchuchard, I get the success status for the adhoc command but the service does not stop on the remote machine.  testserver | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": true, 
    "name": "nginx", 
    "state": "stopped"
}

Comment: I am wondering whether its related to the fact that I need to use sudo to restart the service on the remote machine.  I have tried using become/become_user but the result is the same